# Заполнение поля на сайте и получение результатов выполнения запроса. Как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, ios, веб-программирование

Возможно ли как то заполнить формы на определённом сайте через приложение для IOS, отправить данные серверу. После чего получить данные и обработать их(соответствующие введенным в поля, конечно же)?

Пример: В поле поиска на книжном сайте вводиться название книги, после чего имитируется нажатие Enter и результаты поиска обрабатываются.

Вопрос не стоит в обработке данных. Вопрос касается возможности сымитировать действия пользователя с целью получить данные соответствующие запросу.

Comment: Да можно. Во-первых такая штука как headless browsers вроде phantomjs. В-нулевых надо понимать что такое клиент-серверное взаимодействие. Все эти формочки, кнопочки стрелочки и выпадашечки на клиенте в результате формируют параметры обычного хттп запроса к серверу. И для того чтобы их формировать, имитировать действия пользователя далеко не обязательно

Comment: @Утка Это возможно реализовать на мобильной платформе?

Comment: а, то есть вы не клиент хотите сымитировать а за конкретного юзера что-то сделать?

Comment: Мне кажется Вам сначала надо понять как работате интернет. Почитать там про клиент-серверную архитектуру, http и same origin policy, хотя бы на уровне понимания что это такое.

Comment: @Утка мне нужно дословно вот что: зайти на сайт, ввести данные в поле поиска, обработать полученную страницу но это должно произойти за занавесом. Пользователь должен увидеть только результат.

Comment: В общем случае нельзя. Same origin policy. Интернет не идиоты делали, кулхацкерство так просто не работает.

Comment: @Утка смысл не в хаке а во взаимодействие с сайте через приложение. Кто сказал что это будет личная информация?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44807/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формочки и кнопочки рендерятся браузером только для пользователя.
Ему [браузеру] они не нужны и даже вредны (на рендер тратятся ресурсы и, порой, немалые).
Настоящий запрос делается особым пакетом (HTTP2) или строкой (HTTP1.1).
Что-то типа:

```
http://mybestbookstore.com/api?query=220+Tage+im+Weltraumschiff&author=Martynow+G.
```

Comment: Извините, я немного подправил тему. Мне жаль что я ввел вас в заблуждение по поводу вопроса

Comment: @иванганенко, хм, ладно, хотя часть про HTTP верна и для iOS.

Comment: т.е. я могу отправить запрос в соответствующей форме для сервера что бы получить ту информацию которая мне нужна?

Comment: @иванганенко, да, Вам не нужны формочки чтобы сделать запрос, достаточно сформировать URI и запросить его - там будут результаты. Хотя с формочками удобно и красиво, если подумать, но для запроса они не нужны, тем более не нужно эмулировать их нажатие.

Comment: А если запрос имеет не человекоподобный вид? Пример /wps/portal/home/rp/schedule/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3gTi0C3MMdQb7MANx8XA8_gEGcfNw9XQwNDA6B8pFm8s7ujh4m5j4GBv1GYgYGRn2lwoEFosLGBpzExug1wAEcDArq99KPSc_KTgK4MB7kbSa2hmaklUK1PUEiosYuhhakRRB6fO0HyeFzi55Gfm6pfkBsaURnsqQsAlB5hlQ!!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSmdrS0NsRUpDZ3BSQ1NBL29Ob2dBRUlRaGpFS0lRQUJHY1p3aklDa3FTaFNOQkFOYUEhIS80QzFiOVdfTnIwZ0RFU1pJSlJERVNaTUpRaUlrZmchIS83XzQ4UUZWQVVLNlA1MDYwSVNKTEtHTEQyMDA3LzNQMjFHNTU3NTAwMDkvaWJtLmludi8zMzQwMTU5NzYzNjAvamF2YXguc2VydmxldC5pbmNsdWRlLnBhdGhfaW5mby8lMFNlbGVjdFJvdXRlVmlldy5qc3A!/

Comment: @иванганенко, с кнопочками или нет всё равно придётся разобраться как закодировать такого зверя.

Comment: вы думаете это реально?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44811/discussion-between-other-and--).